# how can set color of icon when inputs are n't empty?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want the color of related icon of inputs are changed when I focus on inputs or when the inputs are not empty.but my code do not work correctly for when inputs are not empty.

```
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="label-login" for="emailInput">Email</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" id="emailInput" />
                        <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="label-login" for="passInput">Password</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" id="passInput" />
                        <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>

                    </div>

   $(document).ready(function () {
     $(".myPanel .form-control").each(function () {
    var valueInput = $(this);
    valueInput.focus(function () {
        valueInput.next().addClass("colorOrange");    
    });

    valueInput.blur(function () {
        valueInput.next().removeClass("colorOrange");
    });
    valueInput.on('input', function () {
        if (valueInput.val().length > 0) {
            valueInput.prev().addClass("lableFocus");
            valueInput.next().addClass("colorOrange");
        } else {
            valueInput.prev().removeClass("lableFocus");
            valueInput.next().removeClass("colorOrange");
        }
    });
   });
});
  .colorOrange{
       color:#FFAE00;
  }
```

Comment: Is this one file? If so, you should surround the javascript by <script> tags...

Comment: your code has a syntax error, maybe you pasted it wrong above? ".colorOrange {...}" is the syntax error.

Comment: Also can you show your CSS classes (colorOrange, etc)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution, I have managed to cut down the length of the code a little. Hope this helps.

```js
$( ".form-control" ).focusin(function() {
  $( this ).next( "i" ).css( "color", "#FFAE00" );
});
$( ".form-control" ).focusout(function() {
  $(this).val().length === 0 ? fontColor = "#000" : fontColor = "#FFAE00";
  $(this).next( "i" ).css( "color", fontColor );
});
```

```css
.colorOrange {
  color: #FFAE00;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="label-login" for="emailInput">Email</label>
  <input type="email" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" id="emailInput" />
  <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="label-login" for="passInput">Password</label>
  <input type="password" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" id="passInput" />
  <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in pure CSS, using the [:valid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:valid) pseudo class. This allows you to do something along the lines of

```
/* html */

    <div class="form-group">
       <label class="label-login" required for="passInput">Password</label>
       <input type="password" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" id="passInput" />
       <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
    </div>

/* css */
input:valid + i.fa-lock {
   color: $your-valid-color;
}
```

A few notes--

- you need to mark the input as required, or else  it will always be
  valid.
- A non-empty type="text" element will be valid
- you can specify a regex pattern to put constraints on what counts as valid, or use the minlength attribute

Check out the full documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input). The standard html form/input fields are pretty powerful, so you can get a lot done with just them.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is with scope. `valueInput` exists in the `.ready()` function, but isn't inherited within the `.blur()` and `.on()` functions. In those use `this`, which is a reference to the element that triggered the event.